# Acquire renderer process id in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chromium

In Electron, the renderer process's pid was exposed by

```
processId = require('remote').getCurrentWindow().getProcessId()
```

which, however, is no longer valid in recent releases (1.4.x, 1.5.x, 1.6.x).

Is there any other way to get the pid of the renderer process, i.e. the pid for the Windows ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `getOSProcessId()` to acquire the renderer's OS pid (not the routing id) was added to [Electron v1.7.1](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v1.7.1). Here is the original [pull request](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/9222).

```
require('electron').remote.getCurrentWebContents().getOSProcessId();
```

Comment: This works great when you are accessing the pid from within the renderer process. For anyone reading, one gotcha I ran into when I was trying to access a renderer's pid from within the main process is that you must wait for the `did-finish-load` event to emit from a window's `webContents` before you can query the pid. Otherwise `window.webContents.getOSProcessId()` will return `0`.

Answer (score 4):

Strangely enough, on Darwin or Linux Mint, with Electron 1.6.7,

```
require('electron').remote.getCurrentWebContents().getProcessId()
```

returns 3, which seems quite small for a valid process id.

However, from the renderer process,

```
process.pid
```

returns the correct renderer process id, and

```
require('electron').remote.process.pid
```

returns the correct main process id.

This can be confirmed by using the Activity Monitor application on Darwin, or the System Monitor application on Linux Mint.

Comment: That's what I'm also confused about. The returned value looks more like an internal windows id other than a valid process id.

Answer (score 3):

The following slightly modified version works for me

```js
require('electron').remote.getCurrentWebContents().getProcessId()
```

Example:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.once('ready', () => {
  var br = new BrowserWindow()
  br.once('focus', () => {
    br.webContents.openDevTools({detach:true})
    br.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
      const remote = require('electron').remote
      console.log(remote.getCurrentWebContents().getProcessId())
    `)
  })
  br.loadURL('http://google.com')
})
```

*Tested on 1.4.13*

Comment: What's the pid printed out? Is it a valid pid, or just a windows routing id?

Comment: it prints `4`, so it seems to be invalid for process id. However, `remote.process.pid` returns valid value here as well, as Mikaeru suggested

Comment: Thanks, that's the routing id rather than the OS process id. The method to acquire the latter was just added in Electron v1.7.1.

Answer (score 2):

As of electron 14 the remote module has been [removed](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#removed-remote-module)

```
// Deprecated in Electron 12:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote


// Replace with:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('@electron/remote')

// In the main process:
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
```